# PHP retrieve data from object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have been working with PHP for some time, I'm using object array more and more and I am a little confused about what is the best way to retrieve data from it.

As I understand, this can be done in 3 different way

here is an array : $array=[ "name"=>"value" ]

```
$array->name;

$array["name"];

$array->{"name"};
```

I noticed that in some case the result is empty. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: What do you mean by "object array"? Something is either an object _or_ an array, but not both, except if you invest into defining an implementation an `ArrayAccess`interface into a class. Objects and arrays are something quite different, you appear to confuse them. Depending on what type of variable you actually work on one or two of the attempts you may simply are not defined in php. But then their result is not "empty", but you get an error. I suggest you take a look into your error log file.

Comment: here `$array->name;` should not work correctly. Because this is the way to access property of object not array. Object is an instance of class on the other hand $array is a collection of variables.

Comment: $array=[ "name"=>"value" ] is an associative array. not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access (associative) arrays with the '[]'-syntax and objects (classes) with the '->'-syntax. See following examples:

```html
<?php

    // accessing (associative) arrays
    $array = ['name' => 'value'];

    echo "1: " . $array->name . "\n";
    echo "2: " . $array['name'] . "\n";
    echo "3: " . $array->{'name'} . "\n";

    // accessing objects (classes)
    class myClass {
        public $name = 'value22';
        public $name23 = 'value46';
    }

    $object = new MyClass();

    echo "4: " . $object->name . "\n";
    echo "5: " . $object->{'name' . '23'} . "\n";
    //echo "6: " . $object['name'] . "\n";

?>
```

**Output**

```
1: 
2: value
3: 
4: value22
5: value46
```

Example #6 will produce a fatal error in PHP, so I commented it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I made mistake between classe and associative array. I was sure to use only associative array...obviously not!